# Unable to deploy basic example HttpRequest1 to Azure Function using VSCODE Python

Tags: python, azure, function, deployment

I cannot figure out why the deployment to Azure Functions is failing.
This is the error output given by VS Code (`Python venv 3.8.8`)

```
14:32:52 eTendersTests: Starting deployment...
14:32:57 eTendersTests: Creating zip package...
14:32:57 eTendersTests: Zip package size: 2.44 kB
14:33:01 eTendersTests: Fetching changes.
14:33:02 eTendersTests: Cleaning up temp folders from previous zip deployments and extracting pushed zip file /tmp/zipdeploy/f670fa18-4068-42c0-925b-752b66739c18.zip (0.00 MB) to /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
14:33:04 eTendersTests: Updating submodules.
14:33:05 eTendersTests: Preparing deployment for commit id '95126602-7'.
14:33:05 eTendersTests: PreDeployment: context.CleanOutputPath False
14:33:05 eTendersTests: PreDeployment: context.OutputPath /home/site/wwwroot
14:33:05 eTendersTests: Repository path is /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
14:33:05 eTendersTests: Running oryx build...
14:33:05 eTendersTests: Command: oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform python --platform-version 3.9 -p packagedir=.python_packages/lib/site-packages
14:33:07 eTendersTests: Operation performed by Microsoft Oryx, https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx
14:33:07 eTendersTests: You can report issues at https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx/issues
14:33:07 eTendersTests: Oryx Version: 0.2.20210120.1, Commit: 66c7820d7df527aaffabd2563a49ad57930999c9, ReleaseTagName: 20210120.1
14:33:07 eTendersTests: Build Operation ID: |Yui9lstuThc=.75fae38b_
14:33:07 eTendersTests: Repository Commit : 95126602-7dce-46da-be06-41ab4abf3a44
14:33:07 eTendersTests: Detecting platforms...
14:33:07 eTendersTests: Detected following platforms:
14:33:07 eTendersTests:   python: 3.9.7
14:33:07 eTendersTests: Version '3.9.7' of platform 'python' is not installed. Generating script to install it...
14:33:08 eTendersTests: Source directory     : /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
14:33:08 eTendersTests: Destination directory: /home/site/wwwroot
14:33:08 eTendersTests: Downloading and extracting 'python' version '3.9.7' to '/tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.7'...
14:33:08 eTendersTests: Downloaded in 0 sec(s).
14:33:08 eTendersTests: Verifying checksum...
14:33:09 eTendersTests: Extracting contents...
14:33:12 eTendersTests: Done in 4 sec(s).
14:33:12 eTendersTests: Python Version: /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.7/bin/python3.9
14:33:12 eTendersTests: Running pip install...
14:33:13 eTendersTests: [04:33:13+0000] Collecting azure-functions
14:33:13 eTendersTests: [04:33:13+0000]   Downloading azure_functions-1.11.2-py3-none-any.whl (206 kB)
14:33:13 eTendersTests: [04:33:13+0000] Installing collected packages: azure-functions
14:33:13 eTendersTests: [04:33:13+0000] Successfully installed azure-functions-1.11.2
14:33:14 eTendersTests: WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 22.1.2 is available.
14:33:14 eTendersTests: You should consider upgrading via the '/tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.7/bin/python3.9 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
14:33:14 eTendersTests: Done in 2 sec(s).
14:33:14 eTendersTests: Preparing output...
14:33:14 eTendersTests: Copying files to destination directory '/home/site/wwwroot'...
14:33:14 eTendersTests: Done in 0 sec(s).
14:33:15 eTendersTests: Removing existing manifest file
14:33:15 eTendersTests: Creating a manifest file...
14:33:15 eTendersTests: Manifest file created.
14:33:15 eTendersTests: Done in 6 sec(s).
14:33:15 eTendersTests: Running post deployment command(s)...
14:33:15 eTendersTests: Generating summary of Oryx build
14:33:15 eTendersTests: Deployment Log file does not exist in /tmp/oryx-build.log
14:33:15 eTendersTests: The logfile at /tmp/oryx-build.log is empty. Unable to fetch the summary of build
14:33:15 eTendersTests: Triggering recycle (preview mode disabled).
14:33:15 eTendersTests: Linux Consumption plan has a 1.5 GB memory limit on a remote build container.
14:33:15 eTendersTests: To check our service limit, please visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#service-limits
14:33:15 eTendersTests: Creating placeholder blob for linux consumption function app...
14:33:15 eTendersTests: Malformed SCM_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE when uploading built content.
14:33:15 eTendersTests: Generating summary of Oryx build
14:33:15 eTendersTests: Deployment Log file does not exist in /tmp/oryx-build.log
14:33:15 eTendersTests: The logfile at /tmp/oryx-build.log is empty. Unable to fetch the summary of build
14:33:15 eTendersTests: Deployment Failed.
14:33:24 eTendersTests: Deployment failed.
14:35:55 eTendersTests: Starting deployment...
14:35:58 eTendersTests: Creating zip package...
14:35:58 eTendersTests: Zip package size: 2.44 kB
14:36:00 eTendersTests: Fetching changes.
14:36:01 eTendersTests: Cleaning up temp folders from previous zip deployments and extracting pushed zip file /tmp/zipdeploy/5d3f2d78-9904-453e-9e73-c833f30cacf4.zip (0.00 MB) to /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
14:36:03 eTendersTests: Updating submodules.
14:36:04 eTendersTests: Preparing deployment for commit id '5adc9561-c'.
14:36:04 eTendersTests: PreDeployment: context.CleanOutputPath False
14:36:04 eTendersTests: PreDeployment: context.OutputPath /home/site/wwwroot
14:36:04 eTendersTests: Repository path is /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
14:36:04 eTendersTests: Running oryx build...
14:36:04 eTendersTests: Command: oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform python --platform-version 3.9 -p packagedir=.python_packages/lib/site-packages
14:36:06 eTendersTests: Operation performed by Microsoft Oryx, https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx
14:36:06 eTendersTests: You can report issues at https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx/issues
14:36:06 eTendersTests: Oryx Version: 0.2.20210120.1, Commit: 66c7820d7df527aaffabd2563a49ad57930999c9, ReleaseTagName: 20210120.1
14:36:06 eTendersTests: Build Operation ID: |yJLJ95+U9fQ=.b4d71421_
14:36:06 eTendersTests: Repository Commit : 5adc9561-c840-47cb-83a4-9ff9451595ed
14:36:06 eTendersTests: Detecting platforms...
14:36:08 eTendersTests: Detected following platforms:
14:36:08 eTendersTests:   python: 3.9.7
14:36:08 eTendersTests: Version '3.9.7' of platform 'python' is not installed. Generating script to install it...
14:36:08 eTendersTests: Source directory     : /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
14:36:08 eTendersTests: Destination directory: /home/site/wwwroot
14:36:08 eTendersTests: Downloading and extracting 'python' version '3.9.7' to '/tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.7'...
14:36:09 eTendersTests: Downloaded in 1 sec(s).
14:36:09 eTendersTests: Verifying checksum...
14:36:09 eTendersTests: Extracting contents...
14:36:13 eTendersTests: Done in 5 sec(s).
14:36:13 eTendersTests: Python Version: /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.7/bin/python3.9
14:36:13 eTendersTests: Running pip install...
14:36:14 eTendersTests: [04:36:14+0000] Collecting azure-functions
14:36:14 eTendersTests: [04:36:14+0000]   Downloading azure_functions-1.11.2-py3-none-any.whl (206 kB)
14:36:14 eTendersTests: [04:36:14+0000] Installing collected packages: azure-functions
14:36:14 eTendersTests: [04:36:14+0000] Successfully installed azure-functions-1.11.2
14:36:15 eTendersTests: WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 22.1.2 is available.
14:36:15 eTendersTests: You should consider upgrading via the '/tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.7/bin/python3.9 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
14:36:15 eTendersTests: Done in 2 sec(s).
14:36:15 eTendersTests: Preparing output...
14:36:15 eTendersTests: Copying files to destination directory '/home/site/wwwroot'...
14:36:15 eTendersTests: Done in 0 sec(s).
14:36:15 eTendersTests: Removing existing manifest file
14:36:15 eTendersTests: Creating a manifest file...
14:36:15 eTendersTests: Manifest file created.
14:36:15 eTendersTests: Done in 7 sec(s).
14:36:16 eTendersTests: Running post deployment command(s)...
14:36:16 eTendersTests: Generating summary of Oryx build
14:36:16 eTendersTests: Deployment Log file does not exist in /tmp/oryx-build.log
14:36:16 eTendersTests: The logfile at /tmp/oryx-build.log is empty. Unable to fetch the summary of build
14:36:16 eTendersTests: Triggering recycle (preview mode disabled).
14:36:16 eTendersTests: Linux Consumption plan has a 1.5 GB memory limit on a remote build container.
14:36:16 eTendersTests: To check our service limit, please visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#service-limits
14:36:16 eTendersTests: Creating placeholder blob for linux consumption function app...
14:36:16 eTendersTests: Malformed SCM_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE when uploading built content.
14:36:16 eTendersTests: Generating summary of Oryx build
14:36:16 eTendersTests: Deployment Log file does not exist in /tmp/oryx-build.log
14:36:16 eTendersTests: The logfile at /tmp/oryx-build.log is empty. Unable to fetch the summary of build
14:36:16 eTendersTests: Deployment Failed.
14:36:33 eTendersTests: Deployment failed.
```

Answer (score 5):

I was also facing this same generic error you are seeing, but the cause for mine was different - it had to do more with installing PyTorch for Azure Functions. The author of this blog has done a great job to explain this: [Azure Functions : install PyTorch and Tensorflow](https://www.alirookie.com/post/azure-functions-install-pytorch-and-tensorflow#:%7E:text=Many%20of%20you%20have%20already,needed%20to%20run%20your%20applications.)

```
    [09:23:12+0000]     Running setup.py install for pytorch: finished with status 'error'
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 22.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.10.4/bin/python3.10 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command. | Exit code: 1 | Please review your requirements.txt | More information: https://aka.ms/troubleshoot-python
\n/opt/Kudu/Scripts/starter.sh oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform python --platform-version 3.10.4 -p packagedir=.python_packages/lib/site-packages

Generating summary of Oryx build
Deployment Log file does not exist in /tmp/oryx-build.log
The logfile at /tmp/oryx-build.log is empty. Unable to fetch the summary of build
Deployment Failed. deployer = Push-Deployer deploymentPath = Functions App ZipDeploy. Extract zip. Remote build.
Remote build failed!
```

Comment: adding the wheel links to the requirements.txt worked for me as described in the blog, and although the deployment now worked, I still got runtime errors for pytorch:
```Exception: OSError: /home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_global_deps.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I couldn't install pytorch.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem and ran this manually:

```
func azure functionapp publish <AZURE_FUNCTION_NAME_GOES_HERE> --build remote
```

I still got the problem related to logs, but the app deployed.

```
...
Generating summary of Oryx build
Deployment Log file does not exist in /tmp/oryx-build.log
The logfile at /tmp/oryx-build.log is empty. Unable to fetch the summary of build
Triggering recycle (preview mode disabled).
Deployment successful.
Remote build succeeded!
```

(I also had switched from a consumption plan to a standard plan at that time so I'm not sure which one helped me work around the issue).

There were some other options to fix this [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx/issues/1503) but they didn't apply to me.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalled all python versions, VS Code, restarted.

Reinstall VSCODE, Python 3.9 (exactly) and created a new Function App (via VS CODE) and deployed.

Comment: If you think that this resolves the issue, please consider marking this as accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

I have received the same error
"Deployment Log file does not exist in /tmp/oryx-build.log".

And tested out tow methods:

1. Use the VSCode extension 'Azure Functions' create Function App.
2. Check the Azure Portal - Function App - Configuration. New Function App maybe miss the key 'AzureWebJobsStorage'.  Need to manually create 'Storage Accounts' and add the Key 'AzureWebJobsStorage'.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> Deployment Log file does not exist in /tmp/oryx-build.log
> 14:36:16 eTendersTests: The logfile at /tmp/oryx-build.log is empty. Unable to fetch the summary of build
> 14:36:16 eTendersTests: Deployment Failed.
> 14:36:33 eTendersTests: Deployment failed.

The Output Terminal error message shows that you may missed some packages in your project.

Make sure you are included all packages in your azure project. Recheck your **requirement.txt** file once before deploying you have included all necessary packages.

**Restart your visual studio** once if still you are not able to deploy your azure functions.

#### Results

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your Function App (not function). Then deploy from VSCode. See if that works. If that doesn't work, then try a function app on a different pricing plan. For me premium plan works fine but not the consumption plan.
[image]

[image]